# Smart way to build REST API

Tags: php, android, api, rest, http

I have online store and writing REST API now.
I cannot choose the best way of building API methods and responses.
I have following url to access product

I need to have ability to specify width and height of image in REST request, so I have already asked this question and advice was to use something like this

```
mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53/image?width=100&height=100
```

This looks really better than previous example.

But now my question is how to retrieve image correctly without sending tons of request.

What do I mean ?

```
mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53/image?width=100&height=100
```

In this url we are set desired dimension, what response should be than ?

It should be image or it should url to image ??

I think it is better to have url of image rather than getting raw image each time.Maybe I am wrong ,please correct me.

So if this method will return url we should make another request to download image.

In this case we have two requests to retrieve image.

I though about setting image url in response to this url

`mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53`

In JSON format

```
{
  "name": "HTC One",
  "id": "1",
  "image_url": "http://mysuperstore.com/images/htc-one.png"
}
```

In this case we will get raw image without any resizing.

There is possible url to get resized image and data in one request.

```
mysuperstore.com/api/categories/40/products/53?width=100&height=100
```

But it seems weird and unclear even for me.

I cannot get how to build this API elegantly without making it redundant.

Please suggest what is the most correct way to follow in this case.
Thank you.

Comment: `mysuperstore.com/api?categories=40&products=53&width=100&height=100`, and you serve the image directly, there's no use in returning a new url that serves the image, when all you wanted was to get a single image.

Comment: I really like this book, perhaps it is of some help for you too: https://leanpub.com/build-apis-you-wont-hate